# Get employee ID from NMBRS API

Tags: invantive-sql, invantive-control, nmbrs

I have to query employee salaries information for statistical analysis. But using invantive-control and invantive query tool all EmployeeId fields are empty. And I need this field to add additional information. My question is how can I get EmployeeID in these tables. I am using the following query:

```
select top 10 PartitionID
,      EmployeeId
,      ID
,      Value 
from   EmployeeSalaries@nmbrs
```

The result table:

[image: ResultTableNoEmployeeID]

I get similar results in tables:

- EmployeeFunctions
- EmployeeEmployments
- EmployeeSchedules

(and other tables miss EmployeeId as well)

Comment: Hi Andrius, this was a problem we have diagnosed some time ago, which has been resolved. You need the latest release to make this working. Please contact Invantive Support to discuss your upgrade options.

Comment: There are in fact two types of reasons why EmployeeID is missing: 1. some APIs don't return the EmployeeID when it is presented as a parameter to the table function. This was added in a recent release. 2. Some APIs contain te EmployeeID, but it is not listed correctly anymore. This was fixed. Some other APIs have EmployeeID and it is still correctly listed.